# What does this error mean? how can I handle this error in Python? KeyError: '*'

Tags: python

When I'm compiling this code:

```
import string

filename = "I:\\udemy\\Assignment 0.txt" # Replace with filename

# Setting up a dictionary of all ascii_lowercase letters to be incremented on each one found
amounts = {letter:0 for letter in string.ascii_lowercase }
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    # reading each line    
    for line in file:
        # reading each word        
        for word in line.split():
            amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1 # Ignore case and increment letter counter
print(amounts)
```

The output is coming:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-89246af63302> in <module>
     10         # reading each word
     11         for word in line.split():
---> 12             amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1 # Ignore case and increment letter counter
     13 print(amounts)

KeyError: '*'
```

What does this error mean? how can I handle this error in Python?

```
KeyError: '*'
```

Comment: `*` isn't in the alphabet

Comment: It means you're trying to look up `'*'` in your `amounts` dictionary, which does not have `'*'` as a key.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - there is no key `*` in `amounts` dict (because it's not part of `string.ascii_lowercase`)

Comment: You can check if the value is in amounts first: `if word[0].lower() in amounts: amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1`

Comment: Oh yes thankyou so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The **error** is coming up as there are instances where a word is not starting with a character falling in **[a-z]**

**solution** - add a **try-except block** to debug

```
try:
    amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1
except:
    print('This ideally does not fall in [a-z]', word[0].lower())
    # If needed add the new find to amounts dictionary
    amounts[word[0].lower()] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, `KeyError` means you try to access a value that is not in the dictionary. You can add a test to ensure working only with letters:

```
if word[0].lower() in amounts:
    amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1
```

I take the opportunity to demonstrate more efficient/pythonic ways to achieve counting the values using python standard modules. In particular `collections.Counter` is a must know/use.

Option 1:

```
import string, re
from collections import Counter

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    amount = dict(Counter([i[0].lower() for i in re.split('\s+', text)
                           if i and i[0] in string.ascii_letters]))
```

Option 2: here we use the '\b[a-zA-Z]' regex to match letters at the beginning of words

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    amount = dict(Counter(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'(\b[a-zA-Z])', text))))
```

example input:

```
This is An example
some words, 
for a quick  test
```

output:

```
{'t': 2, 'a': 2, 'i': 1, 'e': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1, 'f': 1, 'q': 1}
```